Overfull using hbox in Beamer miniframes slideentry
I like Beamer's miniframes that I found convenient to navigation in my presentations.
But it misses a different symbol to localize subsection in my taste.
Therefore, in this goal, I added some lines of code within the slideentry definition.
The graphical result is what I needed.
However, it yields a lot of overfull \hbox (xyz pt too wide) polluting my log files.
Here is a MWE:
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{test}{
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[ignorebg]{section in head/foot}
        \insertnavigation{\paperwidth}
        % \dohead
        \vspace{0.05cm}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\defbeamertemplate*{subsec symbol}{test}{x}


% definition from Beamerbasenavigation.sty
% \def\slideentry#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
\makeatletter
\newlength{\temp@MiniframeSubsecDim}
\renewcommand{\slideentry}[6]{%
   %section number, subsection number, slide number, first/last frame, page number, part number
   \ifnum#6=\c@part\ifnum#1>0\ifnum#3>0%
   \ifbeamer@compress%
      \advance\beamer@xpos by1\relax%
   \else%
      \ifnum#2=0%
         \beamer@ypos@offset=1\relax%
      \fi
      \beamer@xpos=#3\relax%
      \beamer@ypos=#2\relax%
      \advance\beamer@ypos by \beamer@ypos@offset\relax
   \fi%
   %% MODIF: Add subsection symbol to miniframes.
   \ifnum#3=1%\c@subsectionslide=#3 % if =1, so it has been reset  => new section or subsection
      \ifnum#2>0% => this a new subsection
            \settowidth{\temp@MiniframeSubsecDim}{}%\usebeamertemplate{subsec symbol}}%
            \addtolength{\temp@MiniframeSubsecDim}{+1.\beamer@boxsize}%
            \advance\beamer@xpos by1\relax%
            \hbox to 0pt{% I tried to change here 
               \beamer@tempdim=-\beamer@vboxoffset%
               \advance\beamer@tempdim by-\beamer@boxsize%
               \multiply\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@ypos%
               \advance\beamer@tempdim by -.05cm%
               \raise\beamer@tempdim\hbox{%
                  \beamer@tempdim=\beamer@boxsize%
                  \multiply\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@xpos%
                  \advance\beamer@tempdim by -\beamer@boxsize%
                  \advance\beamer@tempdim by -\temp@MiniframeSubsecDim% 
                  \advance\beamer@tempdim by 1pt% I also tried to change here.
                  \kern\beamer@tempdim%
                  \global\beamer@section@min@dim\beamer@tempdim%
                  \hbox{\beamer@link(#4){%
                     % add the new symbol.
                     \usebeamertemplate{subsec symbol}%
                  }}% end \hbox{\beamer@link
               }% end raisebox
            }% end hbox
      \fi% end \ifnum#2>0
   \else
      \ifbeamer@compress%
         % nothing
      \else%
            \advance\beamer@xpos by 1\relax%
      \fi%
   \fi% end \ifnum#3=1
   % END MODIF
   \hbox to 0pt{%
   \beamer@tempdim=-\beamer@vboxoffset%
   \advance\beamer@tempdim by-\beamer@boxsize%
   \multiply\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@ypos%
   \advance\beamer@tempdim by -.05cm%
   \raise\beamer@tempdim\hbox{%
      \beamer@tempdim=\beamer@boxsize%
      \multiply\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@xpos%
      \advance\beamer@tempdim by -\beamer@boxsize%
      \advance\beamer@tempdim by 1pt%
      \kern\beamer@tempdim
      \global\beamer@section@min@dim\beamer@tempdim
      \hbox{\beamer@link(#4){%
         \usebeamerfont{mini frame}%
         \ifnum\c@section=#1%
            \ifnum\c@subsection=#2%
               \usebeamercolor[fg]{mini frame}%
               \ifnum\c@subsectionslide=#3%
               \usebeamertemplate{mini frame}%
               \else%
               \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in current subsection}%
               \fi%
            \else%
               \usebeamercolor{mini frame}%
               \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}%
            \fi%
         \else%
            \usebeamercolor{mini frame}%
            \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}%
         \fi%
         }}}\hskip-10cm plus 1fil%
   }\fi\fi%
   \else%
   \fakeslideentry{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}%
   \fi\ignorespaces
}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section{toto sec}
   \begin{frame}{title of a frame}
      test 1
   \end{frame}
   
\subsection{toto subsec}
   \begin{frame}{title of a frame}
      test 2
   \end{frame}

   \begin{frame}{title of a frame}
      test 3
   \end{frame}

\section{tata sec}
\subsection{tata subsec}
   \begin{frame}{title of a frame}
      test 4
   \end{frame}

\subsection{tati subsec}
\subsection{tati subsec}
   \begin{frame}{title of a frame}
      test 5
   \end{frame}

\end{document}

I understand that somehow I do not respect the 'contract' that I ask to LaTeX about some boxes.
I tried to change different dimensions, it was always destroying the graphical result.
But I have to admit that after hours of fight, I do not really understand how these hbox works here...
So my question is: How can I correct these overfull violations keeping graphical results close to what I have now ?

If the navigation bar already has the layout you want, you could simply suppress the warnings temporarily for the navigation, e.g. something like \hfuzz=10cm 

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz It could be a solution, even if I do not measure its implications. And where do you place this command \hfuzz=10cm ?

I posted an example below.

If you are satisfied with the positioning of the miniframes, you could suppress the overfull warning by increasing the \hfuzz:
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{test}{
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[ignorebg]{section in head/foot}
        \hfuzz=\paperwidth
        \insertnavigation{\paperwidth}%
        % \dohead
        \vspace{0.05cm}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\defbeamertemplate*{subsec symbol}{test}{x}


% definition from Beamerbasenavigation.sty
% \def\slideentry#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
\makeatletter
\newlength{\temp@MiniframeSubsecDim}
\renewcommand{\slideentry}[6]{%
   %section number, subsection number, slide number, first/last frame, page number, part number
   \ifnum#6=\c@part\ifnum#1>0\ifnum#3>0%
   \ifbeamer@compress%
      \advance\beamer@xpos by1\relax%
   \else%
      \ifnum#2=0%
         \beamer@ypos@offset=1\relax%
      \fi
      \beamer@xpos=#3\relax%
      \beamer@ypos=#2\relax%
      \advance\beamer@ypos by \beamer@ypos@offset\relax
   \fi%
   %% MODIF: Add subsection symbol to miniframes.
   \ifnum#3=1%\c@subsectionslide=#3 % if =1, so it has been reset  => new section or subsection
      \ifnum#2>0% => this a new subsection
            \settowidth{\temp@MiniframeSubsecDim}{}%\usebeamertemplate{subsec symbol}}%
            \addtolength{\temp@MiniframeSubsecDim}{+1.\beamer@boxsize}%
            \advance\beamer@xpos by1\relax%
            \hbox to 0pt{% I tried to change here 
               \beamer@tempdim=-\beamer@vboxoffset%
               \advance\beamer@tempdim by-\beamer@boxsize%
               \multiply\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@ypos%
               \advance\beamer@tempdim by -.05cm%
               \raise\beamer@tempdim\hbox{%
                  \beamer@tempdim=\beamer@boxsize%
                  \multiply\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@xpos%
                  \advance\beamer@tempdim by -\beamer@boxsize%
                  \advance\beamer@tempdim by -\temp@MiniframeSubsecDim% 
                  \advance\beamer@tempdim by 1pt% I also tried to change here.
                  \kern\beamer@tempdim%
                  \global\beamer@section@min@dim\beamer@tempdim%
                  \hbox{\beamer@link(#4){%
                     % add the new symbol.
                     \usebeamertemplate{subsec symbol}%
                  }}% end \hbox{\beamer@link
               }% end raisebox
            }% end hbox
      \fi% end \ifnum#2>0
   \else
      \ifbeamer@compress%
         % nothing
      \else%
            \advance\beamer@xpos by 1\relax%
      \fi%
   \fi% end \ifnum#3=1
   % END MODIF
   \hbox to 0pt{%
   \beamer@tempdim=-\beamer@vboxoffset%
   \advance\beamer@tempdim by-\beamer@boxsize%
   \multiply\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@ypos%
   \advance\beamer@tempdim by -.05cm%
   \raise\beamer@tempdim\hbox{%
      \beamer@tempdim=\beamer@boxsize%
      \multiply\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@xpos%
      \advance\beamer@tempdim by -\beamer@boxsize%
      \advance\beamer@tempdim by 1pt%
      \kern\beamer@tempdim
      \global\beamer@section@min@dim\beamer@tempdim
      \hbox{\beamer@link(#4){%
         \usebeamerfont{mini frame}%
         \ifnum\c@section=#1%
            \ifnum\c@subsection=#2%
               \usebeamercolor[fg]{mini frame}%
               \ifnum\c@subsectionslide=#3%
               \usebeamertemplate{mini frame}%
               \else%
               \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in current subsection}%
               \fi%
            \else%
               \usebeamercolor{mini frame}%
               \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}%
            \fi%
         \else%
            \usebeamercolor{mini frame}%
            \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}%
         \fi%
         }}}\hskip-10cm plus 1fil%
   }\fi\fi%
   \else%
   \fakeslideentry{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}%
   \fi\ignorespaces
}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section{toto sec}
   \begin{frame}{title of a frame}
      test 1
   \end{frame}
   
\subsection{toto subsec}
   \begin{frame}{title of a frame}
      test 2
   \end{frame}

   \begin{frame}{title of a frame}
      test 3
   \end{frame}

\section{tata sec}
\subsection{tata subsec}
   \begin{frame}{title of a frame}
      test 4
   \end{frame}

\subsection{tati subsec}
\subsection{tati subsec}
   \begin{frame}{title of a frame}
      test 5
   \end{frame}

\end{document}

